# Property of set of positive Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set and positive Lebesgue measure. Does there exits $a>0$ such that $$\cap_{0\leq x\leq a}E+x$$ is a set of positive Lebesgue measure?

I proved that above is true if $E$ is an interval.

Edit: I changed the question and add the condition that $E$ is compact.

Comment: What guarantees measurability of this uncountable intersection?

Comment: I add that $E$ is compact. So that arbitrary intersection of compact set is compact hence measurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $E$ to be any compact set with positive Lebesgue measure *and* empty interior, for example [the fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). Then for any $a>0$, 
$$\bigcap_{0\leq x \leq a} E +x = \emptyset.$$
(In particular its Lebesgue measure is zero). Indeed, assume by contradiction that there exists $a >0$ such that $\bigcap_{0\leq x \leq a} E+x$ is not empty. Then, there exists $y$ such that $y-x \in E$ for every $0\leq x \leq a$. In other words $[y-a,y] \subset E$. This contradicts the empty interior assumption.